# Catching entries in MySQL with a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Lets say i have tables:

```
user   |online
-------|------
frash--|--1---
hoo----|--0---
pree---|--1---
```

and i only want to fectc frash and pree for display in a html file, what do i do?

Comment: `where online like '%1%'`?

Answer (score 1):

to answer you question directly, this should be pretty straight forward,

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableName
WHERE  online = 1
```

To learn more about joins, see the link below

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 0):

Can you be a bit more specific?  It sounds like you want to use foreign database keys to relate the two tables together.  The easiest way to do this is to make sure that each record in the two tables have a unique id field and then you can reference records together by their unique id's.

Eg,
  Give the user table a "user_id" field.
  Give the online table a "user_id" field that would match the user_id in the user table.

Then you can just do something like...

SELECT user.name FROM user, online WHERE user.user_id = online.user_id

Comment: What i want is so i can collect only the entries with a specific value

Comment: Is that one table and those are two fields you just want to get the records where the user field is frash or pree?  You can just use basic SQL for that.  "SELECT user, online FROM table WHERE user='frash' OR user='pree'"

Answer (score -1):

You must read up on the `where` clause:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm

Comment: -1, that site is almost as bad as w3schools in terms of outdated content that teaches bad practices.  You should probably stop recommending it.